# Find position of first occurrence of a substring in a string

Tags: vb.net

I wan't a method with which to find a string within another string. It should return the position of the first occurrence of the substring. (In VB 2008 !)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx)

Comment: sorry, no. IndexOf takes only ONE char but I want to search for a whole string like "anything" !

Comment: Sorry, no.  IndexOf is overloaded, and I even linked to the right overload for you.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry -> I just discovered that it also takes whole strings. My fault !

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for InStr function, see: [InStr at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

position = instr([stringField] & " ", " ")

Looking for the first blank in what might be an empty string named [stringField]. The ' & " "' avoids an error situation where there are no blanks in [stringField].