# find() like function for vb.net

Tags: vb.net

in C++ there is a function for strings find which has the syntax Str.find(substr) which returns the start index of the substring if it exists. I was wondering if anyone knows of a function that provides the same functionality in VB.Net. I have not been able to find one in my searches thus far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find position of first occurrence of a substring in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932073/find-position-of-first-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Comment: *I have not been able to find one in my searches thus far.* I don't want to sound impolite, but it seem syour research so far did neither include google nor msdn. [How to: Search Within a String (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y7ddk24.aspx)

Comment: @DominicKexel well unfortunately you sound very impolite. The mis understanding for me came from the fact I found many examples where people were searching for single characters using 'A' as opposed to "A" which due to my coding background led me to think that function only worked for characters and not for strings. I have already commented this elsewhere on this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim x as String ="ijoneodfpmwfg"
Dim i as Integer = x.IndexOf("d")
'i will be 6 after execution
```

Comment: Thank you very much this does exactly what I wanted it to. Only reason I did not try this was because the references I found for it said it only found a char as opposed to string.

Answer (score -1):

You shoul really look at this page for that answer.  It will tell you all the things you can do with a string and you may find other answers to questions, before you have to ask them here:

[String Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx)