# How do I check if email is not @courts.state.dc.us and throw error if it's not

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net code. I only want to send email if the email has **@courts.state.dc.us**. How do I check to see if the email has @courts.state.dc.us. If the email has for example jane.doe@gmail.com, I want to throw an exception. 
Exception can say something like "We could not send the email, this email is a none court email".

**Here is my visual studio 2010 code**

```
'Send email
    If Not aobjXmlInputDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("IntegrationConditions/IntegrationCondition/NotificationEvent[@notificationType='PetitionerNotification']") Is Nothing Then
    strPetitionerEmail = aobjXmlInputDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("IntegrationConditions/IntegrationCondition/NotificationEvent[@notificationType='PetitionerNotification']/@petitionerEmailAddress").InnerText
    If Msc.Integration.Utility.Library.v4.ProgramExecution.GetRuntimeEnvironment <> "PROD" Then
    'Make sure email is to court email address e.g mike.mike@courts.state.dc.us 
    'If the email is not xyz@courts.state.mn.us
    'Throw an exception
    'The email was not sent. Email was none court email
    End If
aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseInformationalMessage("Sending petitioner notification", 1)
Msc.Integration.Utility.Library.v4.Email.Send("DC.District.Court@Dccourts.gov", strPetitionerEmail, "Service Information", CreateEmail(aobjXmlInputDoc, objSimpleType), , , True)
End If
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932073/find-position-of-first-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-a-string ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a simple `EndsWith()` check:

```
If Not strPetitionerEmail.Trim().EndsWith("@courts.state.dc.us", _
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
    Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid e-mail. E-mail not sent.", "strPetitionerEmail")
End If
```

You could also probably use `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` as the argument falls outside of a valid range (just one, but...) of e-mail domains.

Then from the calling code, you can catch the exception(s):

```
Try
    SendEmail() ' or however you plan on invoking the above code
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    ' Log the exception?
    ' ex.ParamName contains the parameter name, ex.Message the message
Catch ex As Exception
    ' Log the [unhandled] exception?
    ' ex.Message contains the message
End Catch
```

Note that I've `Trim()`ed the e-mail address beforehand and am ignoring its casing.

Comment: Cory, thanks for your response and help. Could you help me with the exception code please. I want something like

Comment: Thanks Cory for the help. Could you please help me with the exception? I want something like "Invalid email. Email not sent" I am not sure what to put in the try catch..................................................................I am not sure how to code this for the error message                          Try Catch ex As Exception End Try

Comment: @user3781064: This code here would only be responsible for *throwing* the exception. Where are you planning on *catching* it?

Comment: @user3781064: I have updated the answer with some exception handling code.

Comment: @user3781064: Great! Don't forget to mark answers accepted if they provided an accurate solution. Welcome to Stack Overflow!