# check whether comma separated string contains a specific string in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a comma separated string like(111,112,113).Now i want to check whether that **string contains specific string or not.**
for example (111,112,113) contains 111.
and (111,112,113) not contains 114.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find position of first occurrence of a substring in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932073/find-position-of-first-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Comment: No i don't want to find position of particular string i just want to check whether the string contains specific string or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.Split` + `Enumerable.Contains`:

```
Dim token As String() = "111,112,113".Split(","c)
Dim contains111 As Boolean = token.Contains("111")
```